# how to add video tags on each other in html? in video chat application? using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, twilio, videochat

i have a video chat application but it has a bad UI. i wanted to know how can both videos be arranged like this image?

http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--iAgbzO34--/18iygzh4tkhpfpng.png

dont have reputation points sorry, please see the link.

i am using twilio, bootstrap, javascript.

```
<div id="call_tracks" class="modal fade" role="document">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-6" id="local">
       <div id="local-media">
        <video id="video1"></video>
       </div>
       <input id="button-preview" onclick="preview();" type="button" value="Preview My Camera" />
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="remote">
     <div id="remote-media">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/360x270s&text=Remote+Video" />
      <video id="video2"></video>
    </div>
    <p id="remote-video-label" class="video-label">participant video</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<script>

document.getelementbyId(video1);
document.getelementbyId(video2);
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I actually created something similar recently. It didn't use Bootstrap, but it did include the CSS to make a picture in picture style display. It was part of my blog post on creating a [Video chat web component](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/getting-started-with-web-components-building-a-video-chat-widget.html). Here is a [link to the CSS I used](https://github.com/philnash/twilio-video-chat-web-component/blob/web-component-complete/public/twilio-video.html#L9-L33) to create this effect:

[image: A picture in picture video chat.]

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Your answer should stand on its own merit, without the need to refer to any offsite resources.

Comment: Yup, CSS all the way. My HTML is likely to be slightly different to yours, so check into that too. The basic idea is to position the videos absolutely within a container, one to cover the whole of it and the other to float above it and sit down in the bottom right (or left).

Comment: Awesome to hear! Could you mark the answer as correct so that other people can tell this helped, thanks!